# Streamwriter FilleSystem TextFile vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagrid with checkboxes that lets the user to multiple delete. How do I store the deleted records into a comma delimited text file? I am using Access to store my data

My code for delete is

```
Try
    con.Open()
    Sql = "DELETE FROM member WHERE ID = ?"

    With cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = Sql
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 0)
    End With

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).FormattedValue = True Then
            cmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells(1).FormattedValue)
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        End If
    Next

    If result = 0 Then
        MsgBox("nothing.")
    Else
        MsgBox("deleted.")

    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

con.Close()
```

Comment: Please indent your code for a more readable post

Comment: Why not use a group of ids - make the ids in the loop and then delete with one statement

Comment: What do you want to store in the text file? Just the ID or the whole record?

Comment: I have rolled back the edit where you removed a lot of code because without the code the answers make little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your file before starting your loop with a StreamWrite passing the actual filename required
At each loop prepare a string to be written in you file. (Use string.Join to create a comma separated string for your values taken from the gridview

```
Using writer = new StreamWriter(.... your file name here ....)
Try
    con.Open()
    sql = "DELETE FROM member WHERE ID = ?"
    With cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = sql
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 0)
    End With
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
       If row.Cells(0).FormattedValue = True Then
           ' Create a string from your current DataGridView,
           ' Note that I don't know in which columns are the data that
           ' that you want to save, so you need to adjust these readings
           Dim curText = string.Join(",", row.Cells(1).FormattedValue, _
                                          row.Cells(2).FormattedValue, _
                                          row.Cells(3).FormattedValue)


            cmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells(1).FormattedValue)
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

            ' We delete one record for each loop, so we need to check the result for every
            ' loop. If we have a deleted record corresponding to ID passed then we can write
            ' the line that contains the data of the deleted record to the file
            If result > 0 Then
                writer.WriteLine(curText)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    .....

' The End Using closes the file and flushes everything to disk.
End Using
```

Comment: That looks good, is there a way you could help me tailor it to my newly updated delete code because I've changed it. The last one wasn't working as well...

Comment: Please explain what is not working. Do you have any kind of error message displayed?

Comment: Your rewritten example doesn't seems to be wrong. So the next course of action is starting the debugger and step-by-step follow this code to see what really happens here. Is the loop entered at least one time? Is the check for True inside the loop positive?

Comment: Check again my code. The declaration of curText and the writing of a single line for the single deleted record is INSIDE the for loop NOT OUTSIDE. The curText is not declared and inacessible OUTSIDE the loop. I will rewrite the answer to adapt to your new code

Comment: Really the only thing that makes a difference is your willing to learn. If you persist on it the skills will grow as you go along. And remember that this field is so huge that none could call himself an expert of the whole IT industry. Participating to this community will help a lot too. See you again on SO.

Comment: I suggest to post a new question because this will attract the attention of more users.

Comment: Sorry but you really should post a new question. Repeat the question with the full code that you have modified. You could also backtrack with a link to this one if you want to have more context but don't ask for solutions to different problems in old questions. This is the path that leads to what the community calls [Chamaleon Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). And if you really like my attention put a link to your new question here as a comment so I will be notified.

Comment: Hello I have created a question on my old account which I just remembered I had. Here's the link, could you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324706/delete-all-checked-records-in-a-datagridview-streamwriter-vb-net @Steve

Answer (score 0):

Store the record info into temp storage then save it to a file.

```
Dim deletedRecords As New List(Of String)
Try
    con.Open()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).FormattedValue = True Then
         'concatenate the row data into a string
          deletedRecords.Add({this record data})
          sql = "DELETE FROM member WHERE id = '" _
          & CStr(row.Cells(1).FormattedValue) & "'"
          With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
          End With

          result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        End If
    Next
    If result = 0 Then
        MsgBox("No Deleted Record.")
    Else
        MsgBox("The Record(s) has been deleted.")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
con.Close()

'save to text file
Using sw As New StreamWriter({path})
  For Each delRec In deletedRecords
    sw.WriteLine(delRec)
  Next
End Using
```

Comment: I don't know which cells you want so I left that part for you to figure out - it is not copy paste - fill in the {} parts

Comment: So the record is not in the DGV? In the cells?